# org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after main at character 6 of {main}( )

Tags: java, php, json

This is my php code.

```
<?php
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123@123","mysql");
$email=$_POST["email"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"select * from Userdata where email = ? and password = ? ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$name,$email,$password,$phone);
$user = array();
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user[name]= $name;
    $user[email]=$email;
    $user[password]=$password;
    $user[phone]=$phone;        
}
    $users = array_values($user);
    echo json_encode($user);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is my java code.

```
package com.mycompany.nowapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ServerRequests {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5000 * 15;


public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2/myfiles/";
public ServerRequests(Context context) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
}

public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user,
                                      GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
    progressDialog.show();
    new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallBack).execute();
}

public void fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
    progressDialog.show();
    new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallBack).execute();
}

/**
 * parameter sent to task upon execution progress published during
 * background computation result of the background computation
 */

public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallBack;

    public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallBack = userCallBack;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.email));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", user.phone + ""));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                + "Register.php");

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams() {
        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        return httpRequestParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallBack.done(null);
    }

}

public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallBack;

    public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallBack = userCallBack;
    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.email));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                + "FetchUserData.php");

        User returnedUser = null;

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            //JSONObject jObject =  new JSONObject(result.substring(result.indexOf("{"), result.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));

            if (jObject.length() != 0){
                Log.v("happened", "2");
                String name = jObject.getString("name");
                long phone = jObject.getLong("phone");

                returnedUser = new User(name, phone, user.email,
                        user.password);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnedUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
        super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallBack.done(returnedUser);
    }
}
}
```

This is the error I got.

```
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after main at character 6 of {main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\myfiles\FetchUserData.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\FetchUserData.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: </table></font>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <br />
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email' in C:\wamp\www\myfiles\FetchUserData.php on line <i>17</i></th></tr>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>243544</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\myfiles\FetchUserData.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\FetchUserData.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: </table></font>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <br />
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password' in C:\wamp\www\myfiles\FetchUserData.php on line <i>18</i></th></tr>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>243544</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\myfiles\FetchUserData.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\FetchUserData.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: </table></font>
01-18 23:36:10.990 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <br />
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant phone - assumed 'phone' in C:\wamp\www\myfiles\FetchUserData.php on line <i>19</i></th></tr>
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>243544</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\myfiles\FetchUserData.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\FetchUserData.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: </table></font>
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err: {"name":"qwe","email":"qwe","password":"qwe","phone":123123123}
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:379)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.nowapp.ServerRequests$fetchUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:140)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.nowapp.ServerRequests$fetchUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:105)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-18 23:36:11.000 21408-21433/com.mycompany.nowapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am new to php and have a little knowledge about Android. I've done this registration app, the data is storing in the database but when I try to login with same details I am getting this error.

Comment: What's the JSON supposed to look like?

Comment: Ah I see it. never mind

Comment: String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity); print this result , and check if `JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);` has error

Comment: it is printing the html like code which is present in the error log i've posted.

Comment: That's the wrong one, it should be a JSON format, which is not HTML format. Check you php code, and check if ` json_encode($user);` from php code is JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
       String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
       JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Make sure your variable result is correct JSON format ([JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/))

This should be echo from your php code. If you see HTML format text string, which probably something goes from from your php server code, debug into it and check the return results.

Comment: hey buddy am not much into this json and php... tell me what all I am supposed to have and steps to do..

Comment: @Andy, I don't know php either, but `echo json_encode($user);` should the the result that returns from the server to your android app, debug into it and put a breakpoint there and montinor the variable `json_encode($user)`, then check it if it is a valid JSON using json viewer. If you find there are some error from php, then fix the error from php side and then recheck the results.

Comment: Am getting like this


    Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'
    Notice: Use of undefined constant email- assumed 'email'
    Notice: Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password'
    Notice: Use of undefined constant phone - assumed 'phone'

I think the error is in the line
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$name,$email,$password,$phone);

plz help me resolve this..

Comment: It seems you don't get the correct param from http request, where you post from android. check the variable user before you set :    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));, make sure it has correct properties, and then debug into php code and also make sure $email=$_POST["email"];
$password=$_POST["password"]; have correct value

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the FetchUserData.php
You have to change these lines:

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
$user[name]= $name;
$user[email]=$email;
$user[password]=$password;
$user[phone]=$phone;
```

}

to

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
$user['name']= $name;
$user['email']=$email;
$user['password']=$password;
$user['phone']=$phone;
```

}

so just add '....'